# IE issue with jQuery masonry call

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer

I have a masonry call which is working fine in all browsers but IE7 and below. Maybe its just a simple syntax issue, but maybe someone has had experience of this before. Code below:

```
$(function(){
  $('#mainContent').masonry({
    columnWidth: 200, 
    itemSelector: '.threadWrapper:visible',
    resizeable: true,
    saveOptions: true,  
  });
});
```

Below is the error message (line 41 is the fist attribute declaration - columnWidth):

[alt text http://www.kalpaitch.com/info/masonrybug.jpg](http://www.kalpaitch.com/info/masonrybug.jpg)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have an extra `,` after `saveOptions: true`. Maybe IE7 is less tolerant.

Comment: Yes I noticed this after I posted and just tested it. You are dead right. That was all it was. Sorry for this.

Comment: kalpaitch, you should accept this as the right answer by clicking the white checkmark on this post. That way, future users will help you on your other questions, future visitors to this question will know the right answer at a glance, and traveling tech guy will get some extra credit for his hard work.

Comment: yea apologies, just got interrupted by the rugby